Getting undefined value by ajax success data in asp.net
I am calling function from .asmx.cs file by ajax web method. Now, I am getting output undefined value in ajax success.
Here is my code,
<input type="button" id="btnGetStock" value="View" class="button-89" />

$("#btnGetStock").click(function (e) {
    var dataToSend = {
        labelno: document.getElementById("<%=txt_labelno.ClientID%>").value
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FillGridMethod.asmx/QuotationList",
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data.ItemType));
            $("#lbl_type").val(data.ItemType);
        }
    });
});

Here is the .asmx file
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
public void QuotationList(string labelno)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["BranchId"].ToString() == null)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Index.aspx");
        return;
    }
    var quotation = new List<QuotationModel>();
    string constr = cn.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        qryFillGrid = " select ItemType from tbl_StockRunning stock " + System.Environment.NewLine;        
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(qryFillGrid, con);
        con.Open();
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var quotationModel = new QuotationModel
            {
                ItemType = dr[0].ToString().Trim()
            };
            quotation.Add(quotationModel);
        }
    }
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(quotation));
}

Now, when I am doing alert of alert(JSON.stringify(data)); then I am getting value in correct Like [{"ItemType":"GOLD"}] format. But when I am doing alert(JSON.stringify(data.ItemType)); then it getting undefined

Look in the network tab to see if you actually get what you expect

Your data being posted has to match the parameters in the web method. Hence, data:
JSON.stringify({ labelno : dataToSend})

@Godot in network it is showing System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: labelno.

@AlbertD.Kallal if I send data by doing json.stringify i.e. data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend), then it shows error i.e. : System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: labelno.

See my 2 examples below. Note how I do NOT serialize the data before sending. To be fair, you can get cleaner JSON with a data table, but in fact the datatable has boatloads of extra attribuotes like Row.dirty, and a whole bunch more things that you don't want. Hence, in most cases, define a "clean" and "nice" List, and return that. If you make the webmethod "void", and return your own serialized string, then your data is NOT found in the .d (the ".d" is only used if you let the built in serializers do their  job).

Serialization of the object is automatic, and out of the box, that web method supports SOAP, jQuery POST (AJAX), and even a REST call should work.
First up, the parameters sent MUST match the function signature.
So, say I have this:
    First Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <br />

    Last Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:TextBox>

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdWebTest" runat="server" Text="Combine aobve"
        CssClass="btn"
        OnClientClick="mycombine();return false;" />

    <br />
    Result:
        <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:TextBox>


    <script>

        function mycombine() {

            var tFirst = $('#txtFirst').val()
            var tLast = $('#txtLast').val()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '/WebService1.asmx/Combine',
                data: JSON.stringify({ FirstName: tFirst, LastName: tLast }),
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (mydatastuff) {
                    4
                    $('#txtFullName').val(mydatastuff.d)
                },
                error: function (data, success, error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error + " - " + data + " - " + success + " - " + data.value)
                }
            })
        }

    </script>

And the web method is this:
    [WebMethod()]
    public string Combine(string FirstName,  string LastName)
    {
        string sResult = FirstName + " " +  LastName;

        return sResult; 
    }

Note how the return data is nested inside of the .d for the return value. (always disliked this quirk, but it was done for reasons of security).
So, result of above is thus this:

So, to return a "list" of some class object as you have?
Say this method:
    [WebMethod()]
    public List<OneHotel> GetHotels(string City) 
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
             WHERE City = @City AND Active = 1
             ORDER BY HotelName";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = City;
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }

        List<OneHotel> sResult = new List<OneHotel>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in rstData.Rows)
        {
            OneHotel hotel = new OneHotel();
            hotel.HotelName = dr["HotelName"].ToString();
            hotel.City= dr["City"].ToString();
            hotel.Description= dr["Description"].ToString();

            sResult.Add(hotel);
        }
        return sResult;
    }

So, note how we return a List of class objects.
So, now client side becomes this:
        <h3>Show hotels for what City</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdGetHotels" runat="server" Text="Get Hotels"
            OnClientClick="showhotels();return false;"
            />

        <script>

            function showhotels() {

                var tCity = $('#txtCity').val()

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: '/WebService1.asmx/GetHotels',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ City : tCity}),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (mydatastuff) {

                        var mytable = $('#myhotels')
                        $.each(mydatastuff.d, function (index, obj) {
                            var newRow = $("<tr>").appendTo(mytable)
                            $("<td>").text(obj.HotelName).appendTo(newRow)
                            $("<td>").text(obj.City).appendTo(newRow)
                            $("<td>").text(obj.Description).appendTo(newRow)
                        })
                    }
                    ,
                    error: function (data, success, error) {
                        alert("Error: " + error + " - " + data + " - " + success + " - " + data.value)
                    }
                })
            }

        </script>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <table id="myhotels" class="table table-bordered table-hover"
            style="width:30%">
            <tr>
                <th>Hotel Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

And the result is now this:

